# Xamarin Forms UWP Missing Phone Call Manager Assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, window, xamarin.uwp

**PROBLEM**

Working through Xamarin University course [XAM120](https://elearning.xamarin.com/forms/xam120/exercise3/4-add-dialer-impls). Reached a blocker in adding my `IDial` implementation to my UWP project. For some reason my project is not picking up the `PhoneCallManager` API on my system.

Error:

> Error CS1069
>   The type name 'PhoneCallManager' could not be found in the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

Code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;
using Phoneword.UWP;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Phoneword.UWP
{
    public class PhoneDialer : IDialer
    {
        public Task<bool> DialAsync(string phoneNumber)
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract", 1, 0))
            {
                Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI(phoneNumber, "Phoneword");
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following reference to your UWP project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to enable the Phone Dialer capabilities in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

For Dependency Injection to work in Xamarin you need to tell it to couple your class with the correct interface!

So above your **namespace Phoneword.UWP** line place following

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (PhoneDialer))]
```

Look at the tutorial in the docs : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/#Registration

Comment: `using Xamarin.Forms;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;

using Phoneword.UWP;
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PhoneDialer))]` here's my using list and assembly reference, I am still seeing the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Could you adjust your example code in the question to reflect what you have in your project? Because that will give a better overview if it is correct or not.